# How to use Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.RemoveItem

Tags: c#, csproj

I've successfuly added files programatically to my project using the following code:

```
var project = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(projPath);
project.AddItem("Compile", filePath);
```

However, removing a file programatically is giving me a hard time.

Signature:

```
public bool RemoveItem(
    ProjectItem item
)
```

How can I instantiate a `ProjectItem`? I couldn't find any examples.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.removeitem.aspx

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I suppose you would iterate through the Items and remove the one you want to remove. In my case I would like to change one of the items to refer to a different file.

Comment: @tofutim you are right. I couldn't find a simpler way but to iterate all items. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the class I ended up writing. No simple solution for remove.

```
    public static class SourceControlHelper
    {
        public static void CheckoutFile(string filePath)
        {
            TFSAction((workspace) => workspace.PendEdit(filePath), filePath);
        }

        public static void AddFile(this Project project, string filePath)
        {
            CheckoutFile(project.FullPath);
            var projectItem = project.GetProjectItem(filePath);
            if (projectItem != null)
            {
                return;
            }
            var includePath = filePath.Substring(project.DirectoryPath.Length + 1);
            project.AddItem(CompileType, includePath);
            project.Save();
            TFSAction(workspace => workspace.PendAdd(filePath), filePath);
        }

        public static void DeleteFile(this Project project, string filePath)
        {
            CheckoutFile(project.FullPath);
            var projectItem = project.GetProjectItem(filePath);
            if (projectItem == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            project.RemoveItem(projectItem);
            project.Save();
            TFSAction(workspace => workspace.PendDelete(filePath), filePath);
        }

        private static ProjectItem GetProjectItem(this Project project, string filePath)
        {
            var includePath = filePath.Substring(project.DirectoryPath.Length + 1);
            var projectItem = project.GetItems(CompileType).FirstOrDefault(item => item.EvaluatedInclude.Equals(includePath));
            return projectItem;
        }

        private static void TFSAction(Action<Workspace> action, string filePath)
        {
            var workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(filePath);
            if (workspaceInfo == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to initialize workspace info");
                return;
            }
            using (var server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(workspaceInfo.ServerUri))
            {
                var workspace = workspaceInfo.GetWorkspace(server);
                action(workspace);
            }
        }

        private static string CompileType
        {
            get { return CopyTool.Extension.Equals("ts") ? "TypeScriptCompile" : "Compile"; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you did

```
      private static ProjectItem GetProjectItem(this Project project, string filePath)
    {
        var includePath = filePath.Substring(project.DirectoryPath.Length + 1);
        var projectItem = project.GetItems(CompileType).FirstOrDefault(item => item.EvaluatedInclude.Equals(includePath));
        return projectItem;
    }
```

in your **GetProjectItem** method:

replace that:

```
var projectItem = project.GetItems(CompileType).FirstOrDefault(item => item.EvaluatedInclude.Equals(includePath));
```

with this:

```
       var projectItem = project.GetItems("Compile").ToList()
            .Where(item => item.EvaluatedInclude.Equals(includePath)).FirstOrDefault();
```

using **.FirstOrDefault()** will bring it to have just first item of all files. i used **.ToList()** and made it work with all my items which have same **EvaluatedInclude**. its totally worked for my.